# Trouble implementing a line-by-line file parser in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io, c++11

I have trouble implementing a simple file parser in C++11 which reads a file line by line and tokenizes the line. It should properly manage its resources. Usage of the parser should be like:

```
Parser parser;
parser.open("/path/to/file");
std::pair<int> header = parser.getHeader();
while (parser.hasNext()) {
    std::vector<int> tokens = parser.getNext();
}
parser.close();
```

So the `Parser` class needs one member `std::ifstream file` (or `std::ifstream* file`?)

1) How should the constructor initialize `this->file`?

2) How should the `open` method set `this->file` to the input file?

3) How should the next line from the file get loaded into a string?
(Is this what you would use: `std::getline(this->file, line)`) ?

Can you give some advice? Ideally, could you sketch out the class as a code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `Parser` is probably in a pretty useless state once you've constructed it and before you've opened the file, I would suggest having your use case look something like this:

```
Parser parser("/path/to/file");
std::pair<int> header = parser.getHeader();
while (parser.hasNext()) {
    std::vector<int> tokens = parser.getNext();
}
parser.close();
```

In which case, you should use the constructor's member initialization list to initialise the `file` member (which, yes, should be of type `std::ifstream`):

```
Parser::Parser(std::string file_name)
  : file(file_name)
{
  // ...
}
```

If you kept the constructor and `open` member function separate, you could just leave the constructor as default because the `file` member will be default constructed giving you a file stream that is not associated with any file. You would then get `Parser::open` to forward the file name to `std::ifstream::open`, like so:

```
void Parser::open(std::string file_name)
{
  file.open(file_name);
}
```

Then, yes, to read lines from the file, you want to use something similar to this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
  // Do something with line
}
```

Good job for not falling into the trap of doing `while (!file.eof())`.

Comment: Does `std::getline` work the same if it is not called from a while loop but each time `getNext()` is invoked?

Comment: @cls Yes, it'll work exactly the same. Make sure you check that it was successful with `if (std::getline(file, line))`.

Answer (score 3):

It can be designed in many ways.

1. You may ask the user to provide you a stream instead of specifying a filename.
   That will be more generic and will work in all streams.

That way you should have a `std::ifstream&` member variable though you can have a pointer type  as well but you need to do `*_stream <<` to invoke any operator.

1. If you take a file, you mat construct a stream in your constructor and close it if open in destructor

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is an alternative to feeding the name of the file to `Parser`: you could feed it a `std::istream`. What's interesting in this is that this way any derived class of `std::istream` can be used, and thus you could feed it, for example, a `std::istringstream`, which makes it easier to write unit-tests.

```
class Parser {
public:
    explicit Parser(std::istream& is);

    /**/

private:
    std::istream& _stream;
    /**/
};
```

Next, comes iteration. It is not idiomatic in C++ to have a `has` followed by a `get`. `std::istream` supports iteration (with an input iterator), you could perfectly design your parser so it does too. This way you will have the benefit of compatibility with many STL algorithms.

```
class ParserIterator:
    public std::iterator< std::input_iterator_tag, std::vector<int> >
{
public:
    ParserIterator(): _stream(nullptr) {} // end

    ParserIterator(std::istream& is): _stream(&is) { this->advance(); }

    // Accessors
    std::vector<int> const& operator*() const { return _vec; }
    std::vector<int> const* operator->() const { return &_vec; }

    bool equals(ParserIterator const& other) const {
        if (_stream != other._stream) { return false; }

        if (_stream == nullptr) { return true; }

        return false;
    }

    // Modifiers
    ParserIterator& operator++() { this->advance(); return *this; }

    ParserIterator operator++(int) {
        ParserIterator tmp(*this);
        this->advance();
        return tmp;
    }
private:
    void advance() {
        assert(_stream && "cannot advance an end iterator");

        _vec.clear();

        std::string buffer;
        if (not getline(*_stream, buffer)) {
            _stream = 0; // end of story
        }

        // parse here
    }

    std::istream* _stream;
    std::vector<int> _vec;
}; // class ParserIterator

inline bool operator==(ParserIterator const& left, ParserIterator const& right) {
    return left.equals(right);
}

inline bool operator!= (parserIterator const& left, ParserIterator const& right) {
    return not left.equals(right);
}
```

And with that we can augment our parser:

```
ParserIterator Parser::begin() const {
    return ParserIterator(_stream);
}

ParserIterator Parser::end() const {
    return ParserIterator();
}
```

I'll leave the `getHeader` method and the actual parsing content to you ;)